# Is the Intersection of two one-sided confidence intervals equivalent to the two-sided confidence interval?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, equivalence, tost

I am interested in testing for equivalence. I know about the TOST procedure, but many people who I work with do not, so I wanted to apply a method that they are more familiar with it. Specifically, I was about to use the two-sided $1-\alpha$ confidence interval of an estimate $\hat{\theta}$ to check whether this estimate lies within a predefined equivalence interval $(\theta_L,\theta_U)$.

But I am hesitating after reading the following statement at the [website](https://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/20/help-and-how-to/statistics/equivalence-tests/supporting-topics/confidence-intervals-in-equivalence-testing/) of the software Minitab:

> [...] the confidence interval for equivalence also considers the additional
> information of the lower and upper limits of the equivalence interval.
> Because the confidence interval incorporates this additional
> information, a (1 – alpha) x 100% confidence interval for equivalence
> is in most cases tighter than a standard (1 – alpha) x 100% confidence
> interval that is calculated for a t-test.

In another [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125410/equivalence-testing-tost-method-why-ci-of-90) on Stack Overflow, Horst Grünbusch made an interesting statement:

> The TOST-CI is simply the intersection of the one-sided CIs.

Assuming this statement is true, then my understanding is that for any test statistic $\theta$ with symmetrical distribution, the intersection of the one-sided $1-2\alpha$ confidence intervals should be identical with the one-sided $1-\alpha$ confidence interval. I would like to ask:

1. Is the cited statement by Horst Grünbusch true?
2. For which test statistics is the two-sided confidence interval not identical to the intersection of the one-sided confidence intervals (i.e. the TOST-CI)?
3. Can one give an intuition, why the TOST-CI would "in most cases be tighter", as indicated by Minitab?