# Lower limit p-value is significant but not the NHST p value in Equivalence testing, what's the interpretation?

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value, interpretation, equivalence

I'm testing two groups for equivalence in exercise self-efficacy using the `TOSTER` package in R. I ran a Mann-Whitney U test (`wilcox_TOST`). The lower limit p value is significant but not the NHST and upper limit p values. The confidence interval partially falls in the predefined equivalence limit (the lower side of it falls in the equivalence limit). The confidence interval also includes zero. How should I interpret this? I know this means that the equivalence tests did not reject both null hypotheses; we cannot reject effects more extreme than the equivalence limits but how should we interpret the NHST p value?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing equivalence testing via two one-sided tests (that's where the TOST comes from). You haven't explained anything about your data so I'm going to use the `TOSTER::wilcox_TOST` example, which as luck would have it demonstrates this exact scenario.

The problem with hypothesis testing is that these are always conducted under the assumption that $H_0$ is true, and a low probability of observing a certain test statistic under this assumption is seen as evidence against it. When testing equivalence you're exactly trying to *prove* what is usually $H_0:\theta_1-\theta_2=0$ however, and a 'regular' hypothesis test doesn't allow you to infer that.

This is why such equivalence tests are actually conducted as *two* tests against some equivalence boundary $\Delta$ (because you can still only ever achieve some probabilistic limit and not exactly $0$), their hypotheses are:

$$
H_{0-}:\theta_1-\theta_2\le{-}\Delta\ \mathrm{vs.}\ H_{A-}:\theta_1-\theta_2>{-}\Delta
$$
$$
H_{0+}:\theta_1-\theta_2\ge\Delta\ \mathrm{vs.}\ H_{A+}:\theta_1-\theta_2<\Delta
$$

Rejection of *both* of the above nulls allows you to conclude that ${-}\Delta<\theta_1-\theta_2<\Delta$, establishing equivalence. If the test is conducted at $\alpha$ this is equivalent to the $1-2\alpha$ confidence interval of $\theta_1-\theta_2$ falling entirely within $]{-}\Delta,\ \Delta[$. See also [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125410/equivalence-testing-tost-method-why-ci-of-90) for a bit more details on why you don't need to correct this for multiplicity for example.

With that background established, let's dive into a data example from `TOSTER` that uses $\Delta=3$:

```
TOSTER::wilcox_TOST(mpg ~ am, data = mtcars, eqb = 3)
>            Test Statistic p.value
> NHST                 42.0   0.002
> TOST Lower           73.0   0.975
> TOST Upper           18.5 < 0.001
```

These results should match your scenario except that the lower/upper test results are swapped. But what does this mean?

1. The default null hypothesis that $\theta_1=\theta_2$ was rejected at $\alpha=0.05$. This does not matter, because they may very well not be *exactly* the same but still be equivalent up to that margin $\Delta=3$.
   Honestly, I don't know why `TOSTER` gives you this result.
2. We did not reject $H_{0-}$ above, so there is not much evidence to support that $\theta_1-\theta_2>{-}3$.
3. $H_{0+}$ *was* rejected, so there is support for $\theta_1-\theta_2<3$.

This being a Wilcoxon test there isn't really a single summary statistic of the 'stochastic exceedance' that it tests (unlike the t-test and the mean for example), but we can use the median as a first approximation:

```
with(mtcars, tapply(mpg, am, median))
>    0    1 
> 17.3 22.8
```

Looks like a ballpark estimate of $\theta_1-\theta_2$ is on the order of $-5.5$, which matches with what our hypothesis tests were telling us above.

*Edit*: There is a [better](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/404971/wilcoxon-signed-rank-test-help-on-interpretation-of-pseudo-median) summary statistic and confidence interval for these tests in the pseudomedian (one sample) or Hodges-Lehmann shift estimator (difference of two samples). This is calculated by `wilcox.test` though will [not be exact](https://aakinshin.net/posts/r-hodges-lehmann-problems/) if there's ties or zeroes in your data. The exact HL shift in this case is $-6.8$.

Finally, you can very easily run these tests by calling the base R `wilcox.test` (or `t.test`, or..) directly:

```
## 'NHST'
wilcox.test(mpg ~ am, data=mtcars)
> W = 42, p-value = 0.001871

## Lower
wilcox.test(mpg ~ am, data=mtcars, mu=-3, alternative="greater")
> W = 73, p-value = 0.9749

## Upper
wilcox.test(mpg ~ am, data=mtcars, mu=3, alternative="less")
> W = 18.5, p-value = 3.013e-05
```

**Addendum**

I realise that I didn't answer the question 'but what if we don't reject $H_0$?'. This does not *establish* equivalence because of the reasons I mentioned in my second paragraph. It may very well mean that you haven't estimated $\theta_1-\theta_2$ with sufficient precision to say that it *isn't* zero, but that doesn't mean that it *is*.

Continuing my example, we were interested in demonstrating that manual & automatic transmission cars were within 3 miles per gallon of one another. If I tell you, yeah, the difference is somewhere between -40 and +30 mpg (including zero! *P*=0.87 under the null), is that good evidence that they are indeed equal? No, by doing this you could underpower your study and *always* end up with that result.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate response! it's getting clearer now. My only issue is that both my NHST p value and upper limit p value are not significant but the lower limit p value is. I mean how can this happen? shouldn't the NHST p value be significant when at least one of the lower/upper limit p value is also significant?

Comment: @Lily No, returning to the CI definition and referring to [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Equivalence_Test.png) image, the example was B (CI excludes 0 but covers one equivalence bound) whereas yours is D (CI does not exclude 0 and covers one equivalence bound). Sorry, I wrote it up & only then realized that the null hypothesis test differed from yours. Notice how the null says nothing about equivalence either (A vs. C).

Comment: There is one scenario not shown in that image where none of the hypotheses would be rejected, which is a CI that covers both bounds plus zero. This would be my addendum of a way underpowered estimate, from which you can conclude just about nothing. I also edited in a better point estimate and CI for the Wilcoxon test as the pseudomedian and Hodges-Lehmann location shift (check out that blog link for how to calculate the 'exact' CI).